# Javascript while loop where condition is a promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Is it possible to make a native JavaScript `while` loop where the condition is a promise?

Edit:
What I'm trying to do is implement a check before uploading a file to firebase storage, to see if a file with the same name already exists in the firebase storage. If there is already a file with the same name then add a random suffix and check again.

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(fileName);

while(storageRef.getDownloadURL()) {
    // create random number in between 0 and 100
    var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);    
    storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(fileName + random);
}

storageRef.put(file);
```

Comment: you probably want some sort of recursive function. Include your code to demonstrate your exact problem/requirement

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do. Technically you can make a loop with a promise being the condition but loop will exit immediately because until promise returns it will be false. Not that you can't invert it but explain what do you need?

Comment: A promise is not an observable. It will be resolved or rejected at some time. It does not provide a stream of values.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is it possible to make a native JavaScript while loop where the condition is a promise?

No, it is not.

There are a couple problems with trying to do that:

1. With ES6 standard promises, there is no way to directly test the value of a promise.  The only access to the eventually resolved value is with `.then()`.  You can't do `while (p !== resolved)`.
2. Even if you could loop on the promises value, because Javascript is event driven and single threaded, if you did do a loop, then the asynchronous operation of the promise could never run and the promise could never get resolved anyway.

Instead, you simply use:

```
p.then(function(result) {
    // process result here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // process error here
});
```

If there's more you wanted to do in your loop, you would have to disclose that actual code before we could advise further on how to best do that.

---

If you want to repeat some operation until some condition, then just put that operation in a function, test the condition in the `.then()` handler and if you want to repeat, then just call the function again.

```
function doSomething() {
    // some async operation that returns a promise
}

function next() {
    return doSomething.then(function(result) {
        if (result < someValue) {
             // run the operation again
             return next();
        } else {
             return result;
        }
    });
}

next().then(function(result) {
      // process final result here
}).catch(function(err) {
    // process error here
});
```

---

**EDIT:** With ES7, you can use `async` and `await`.  It won't really be a `while` loop, but it will obviate the need for a while loop because you don't have to "poll" the asynchronous value at all.

```
async function f() {
   let value = await somePromise;
   // put code here to execute after the promise
   console.log(value);
}
```

The internal execution of function `f()` will be paused until the promise resolves or rejects.  Note that the caller of `f()` will not be paused.  `f()` will return a promise immediately as soon as the `await` line is executed.  That promise itself will resolve and reject when the internal execution of `f()` finally finishes.

Comment: how could this be implemented with a set-timeout between so there is a delay between retries?

Comment: @Scott - See how the delay/retry works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57792389/native-js-promise-retry-wrapper/57793057#57793057) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522955/js-handle-multiple-sequential-failed-async-requests/49523085#49523085).

Comment: It seems in your example that the next().then will execute immediately after the first time through, regardless of if next() is called recursively or returned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is!

What you're looking for are generators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators.

I prefer using Observables [e.g. RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) for more complex stuff.